# Blas seems very slow

Tags: c++, python, numpy, blas

I am comparing matrix multiplications on my machine, and it seems like the c++ blas is very slow. It takes about 4 seconds to multiply a 1000x1000 matrix, and the same time required in python is about 1.5 seconds. I think there might be something wrong with the linking, but I really do not know much how to fix these kind of things. Here is the c++ code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>
using namespace std;


double diffclock(clock_t clock1,clock_t clock2) { double diffticks=clock1-clock2; double diffms=(diffticks*1000)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC; return diffms; }




int
main (void)
{
  double* a=new double[1000*1000];

  double* b=new double[1000*1000];

  double* c=new double[1000*1000];

  for (int i=0;i<1000*1000;i++){
  a[i]=i;
  b[i]=i/5+i*i/100;}

  gsl_matrix_view A = gsl_matrix_view_array(a, 1000, 1000);
  gsl_matrix_view B = gsl_matrix_view_array(b, 1000, 1000);
  gsl_matrix_view C = gsl_matrix_view_array(c, 1000, 1000);

  /* Compute C = A B */
  cout<<"start"<<endl;
  clock_t begin=clock();

  gsl_blas_dgemm (CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans,
                  1.0, &A.matrix, &B.matrix,
                  0.0, &C.matrix);
  clock_t end=clock();
  cout<<double(diffclock(end,begin))<<endl;

  return 0;  
}
```

I am compiling using 
    //g++ -o program mm.cpp -I/home/gsl/include -lm -L/home/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas

The python code is

```
    import time
import numpy as np



n=1000
a=np.zeros((n,n))
b=np.zeros((n,n))
for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n):
        a[i,j]=i*n+j
        b[i,j]=(i*n+j)/5+(n*i+j)**2/5
print "start"
start=time.time()
c=np.dot(a,b)
end=time.time()
print end-start
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe the GSL uses a "standard" implementation, and numpy an optimized one (Intel MKL or alike) ?

Comment: I tested your codes in my box. The C++ program, compiled with the same flags, run in 3.3 secs, the python code in 6.0 secs... However, I'm using vanilla gsl from Ubuntu, while you seem to be using one installed at /home.... did you compile it yourself? if so, how did you compile it?

Comment: Maybe, but how to I check that/fix that? Is there some quick fix? I really am a newbie when it comes to linking/compiling/installing libraries.

Comment: Yes I compiled it myself. It was a mess, I recompiled like 10 times before it manages to work (I downloaded the package and followed the instructions inside with make/configure etc)

Comment: Make sure you compiled with optimization turned on (-O2 or -O3), and add the optimization flag for your program as well.

Comment: what do you mean by adding the optimization flag to my program?

Comment: From what I remember gsl uses standard configure, so you basically do $ CCFLAGS=-O2 ./configure --prefix=/home/myself/whereiputmystuff and then make...

Comment: Running your DGEMM with a 4 core threaded mkl BLAS only takes 41 microseconds. @arbautjc: as a note numpy does not use a BLAS unless you specify one at compile time or some precompiled binaries also include this.

Comment: I had precompiled binaries in mind, such as the famous [Gohlke repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), which is only for Windows, unfortunately.

Comment: On a side note, there's no need for the loops in building `a` and `b` in numpy.  Just do `i, j = np.mgrid[:n, :n]; a = i*n+j; b = (i*n+j)/5+(n*i+j)**2/5`.  (Though you may want to explicitly cast `i` and `j` as floating point arrays before the calculation.)

Answer (score 3):

The subroutines in BLAS are a de facto standard, and a whole slew of optimized and vendor-specific libraries exist that implement the interface. Both numpy and the gsl can be linked against a variety of different BLASes (or in some circumstances use their own implementations), but from this perspective both numpy and the gsl are pretty much wrappers -- the performance you get is basically dependent only on the BLAS that they're linked against.

With the GSL, it's relatively easy to link against an alternative BLAS. There are some instructions here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Linking-with-an-alternative-BLAS-library.html

Intel's MKL is one BLAS that is generally quite fast (at least if you don't have an AMD cpu) but notoriously difficult to link against. They even have a web application to help you write the link line: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor. I have had pretty good luck with OpenBLAS (http://www.openblas.net/), getting performance thats within 1 or 2 percent of MKL on an i7-3770K CPU. OpenBLAS is also pretty easy to compile; it's much less of a headache than ATLAS.

Once you get OpenBLAS, either by compiling from source or downloading from your package manager if you're on a *nix, your modified compilation line would be basically

```
g++ -o program mm.cpp -I/home/gsl/include -lm -L/home/gsl/lib -lgsl -lcblas -lopenblas
```

Comment: Have you any suggestions for linking GSL with MKL on MSVC?